# Can ditto turn into a shiny version of a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

We know that ditto could transform into any Pokemon that it could encounter. Does a normal ditto could turn into a shiny version of a Pokemon that it encountered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the *Pokemon Games*, a regular ditto would end up tranforming to the shiny pokemon it battles. However, in the anime, the *Transform* attack seems to be a lot more unique. For example

- In the anime episode, *Ditto’s Mysterious Mansion*, while ditto could tranform into any pokemon, its eyes and mouth wouldn’t change.
- In the anime episode, *Imitation Confrontation*, there is a ditto which can transform into any pokemon but cannot match the size of the same. It transforms into a mini sized Onix.
- In the manga, Ditto’s transformation is not only limited to transforming into pokemon. In the pokemon adventures manga, Green with the help of ditto, disguises herself into looking like Sabrina to infiltrate Silph Co.

Hence, in conclusion, I don’t see why there is no reason as to why Ditto can’t transform into a shiny pokemon.

Comment: juts to point out with your first dot point, after Team Rocket kidnaps the Ditto and they get angry at it because of it's face (i belief it transformed into Meouth) it fixed up it's face so it looked like a proper transformation so it's flaw was more a temporary thing

Comment: @Memor-X I am aware of the same. I was trying to indicate that in the anime ditto's transform isn't always the vanilla transform we see in the games.